# Can I assign or return a struct with unassigned elements in C?

Tags: c, struct, initialization, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

In C, using an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior. Including:

```
int x;
int y = x;
```

However, suppose I have the following:

```
struct Struct {
    int a;
    int b;
};
struct Struct s;
s.a = 1;
struct Struct s0 = s;
return s; // Assuming an enclosing function with the correct return type
```

Does the above code invoke undefined behavior, in the case that some, but not all, of the elements have been assigned to?

Comment: Nops, it doesn't invoke UB for the second case as long as you don't access `s.b`.

Comment: @DavidRanieri So assigning `s` to `s0` is fine, but trying either `s.b` or `s0.b` would be UB?

Comment: Yes, your  assumptions are correct, but remember: Always code as if the person who will maintain your code is a maniac serial killer who knows where you live :)

Comment: @nicomp What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: @user16217248 kinda hard to answer that!

Comment: @nicomp What does the 'mapped to memory' part mean?

Comment: "In C, using an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior." No, strictly it isn't.

Comment: @nicomp No, it's not undefined behavior.

Comment: @nicomp unspecified behaviour (or implementation defined) != undefined behaviour

Comment: This code won't compile, so the correct answer is that no undefined behaviors can be hit...  Perhaps you could clarify with code corrections?  If I were to take a stab at correcting this code, I'd try to keep in the spirt of answering the direct question about partial structure assignment's being accessed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not adequately addressed by the C standard, but a reasonable C implementation supports using a whole structure when some members are uninitialized. And there is a simple workaround for any C implementation.

Note that “In C, using an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior” is not entirely true. The value of an uninitialized object with automatic storage duration is *indeterminate* per C 2018 6.7.9 10. Using the value of such an object has undefined behavior **if** its address is not taken, per C 2018 6.3.2.1 2:

> … If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the `register` storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.

Thus, to ensure using a structure does not have undefined behavior, it is merely necessary to take its address. Say you have some structure object `s`. Then we can take its address (and discard it) simply by putting `(void) &s;` in the code. By taking its address, we prevent the object from possibly being declared `register`, so 6.3.2.1 2 will not apply.

There could still be some concern that using an object with an indeterminate value might encounter a trap representation. However, this does not occur for structures, per 6.2.6.1 2:

> … The value of a structure or union object is never a trap representation, even though the value of a member of the structure or union object may be a trap representation.

That paragraph tells us the C committee intended C programs to be able to use whole structures even if their members were not all initialized. 6.3.2.1 2, about undefined behavior for some uninitialized objects was added later to provide for a Hewlett-Packard feature that allows the processor to track uninitialized registers. When that addition was made, the committee did not add a statement similar to 6.2.6.1 2 tell us that it would not apply to a structure.

My sentiment would be that 6.2.6.1 2 indicates the intent is for it to be safe to copy whole structures and 6.3.2.1 2 is not intended to change that. However, to be entirely safe, taking the address of the structure as explained above ensures accessing the structure will not have undefined behavior regardless of one’s interpretation of the standard in this regard.

Answer (score -1):

The question states that

```
int x;
int y = x;
```

is undefined behavior.

That's wrong. The `x` has an "indeterminate value" but that's not the same as undefined behavior.

The standard allows for trap representations but that's very rare for `int` on mainstream processors so let's forget about traps.

In that case `y` will get "some value" and hold on to it while accessing `x` may produce (according to the standard) different results whenever accessed.

Exactly the same applies for the `struct`. No undefined behavior. Just  indeterminate values. Returning the struct or assigning to another struct won't make any difference. The object is there... you just don't know what access to `s.b` will give you.

Comment: While C89 didn't formally characterize "trap representations", I think the clear expectation was that if code attempted to read from an indeterminate-valued object of a type where some bit patterns might trigger weird side effects, such attempt might trigger such side effects, but behavior would generally be consistent with the object's storage holding some possible bit pattern.  Later versions of the Standard, however, add additional special provisions for automatic objects, while failing to say anything meaningful about structures.

Answer (score -1):

The actual question and the intended question seem to be different.  Answering the actual question, the short answer is no, it won't even compile - so it can't create any undefined behaviors at all.

It appears the intended question is: "will returning a partially assigned structure cause an undefined behavior?"  The return implies that this is inside of a function, so maybe that is an unwanted complication, but lets entertain it for a moment, and wrap the op's original code in a function and a few extra elements (like a main) for points of discussion:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct Struct {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct Struct myfunc(void)
{
    struct Struct s;
    s.a = 1;
    struct Struct s0 = s;
    return s;
}

void main(void)
{
    struct Struct bob = myfunc();
    bob.b = 2;
    printf("bob.a --> %d, bob.b --> %d",bob.a, bob.b);
}
```

To start, the first copy of `s` into `s0` is going to cause a copy, which means that each field is accessed, which means that you have an undefined behavior here.  Assuming that doesn't cause a crash in your particular compiler, then the return is also an undefined behavior.

Below all that in the main, assuming no crashes because the compiler handled it anyway, the `bob.b = 2` assignment makes things OK for the print statement.  So you can get away with undefined behavior if your compiler is complicit in the bad code. But without that extra assignment, you'd have undefined behavior on access in the `printf()` call as well, and complicit compiler or not, the issue would actually finally be evident.

Of course, pointers to structs are often used as well, and that gets trickier...  with the pointers, you're only copying an address, so you won't have undefined behavior until you access the fields.  Of course, you also have to consider deep copy vs shallow copy, and if you keep `s` as a local variable to that function, you'll have OTHER undefined behavior because now you'll have an illegal pointer dereference as it was pointing to stack that is out of scope once you're back in the `main`.  But, if you put that struct `s` in the global scope, then all of a sudden you can assign field `b` and be completely fine, without ever having undefined behaviors from accessing uninitialized variables.

Of course, then you have the mess of variables in global scope....

Comment: Re “with the pointers, you're only copying an address, so you won't have undefined behavior until you access the fields”: If you have taken the address of an object, then it could not have been declared `register`, and then the behavior of accessing it when it is not initialized is not undefined, per C 2018 6.3.2.1 2. It is not generally true that accessing an uninitialized object has undefined behavior; this is so only if the conditions specified in 6.3.2.1 2 are met.

Comment: I was referring to accessing the uninitialized fields that are pointed to.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think the Committee ever considered that question, or that members would have a consensus understanding of how to answer it.  A weakness with the Standard is that its abstraction model can't usefully deal with situations where optimizations may affect program behavior in ways that may be irrelevant to application requirements.  Consider, for example:

```
struct blob { int count; char arr[32]; } x,y;
void test1(void)
{
  struct blob temp;
  temp.count = 2;
  temp.arr[0] = 1;
  temp.arr[1] = 2;
  x = temp;
  y = temp;
}
void test(void)
{
  test1();
  fwrite(&x, 1, sizeof (struct blob), someFile);
  fwrite(&y, 1, sizeof (struct blob), someFile);
}
```

If nothing in the universe would ever care about the contents of dat[2..31] in the structures that get written to the file, the most efficient way to process the code would be to have `test` simply write the leading portions of `x` and `y`, leaving the rest holding whatever they held before the call.  I don't think there would have been a consensus among Committee members that such an optimization should be forbidden, but there's no way to allow it without characterizing the `test()` function above.  On the flip side, if the only way for a programmer to guarantee anything about program behavior would be to ensure that all portions of `temp` were written before copying it to `x` and `y`, then the "optimization" that was just to justify treating `test1()` as invoking UB would be rendered moot and useless, thus meaning there would be no reason not to treat unwritten portions of `temp.arr` as holding Unspecified values (which would result in `x.arr` and `y.arr` holding identical contents).